# React Native Firebase not Off-line

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

So guys I have my app working 100% with `Firebase` and `react-native` but the problem is if I try to disconnect the internet the app don't get cached information.

On official `Firebase` says that `firebase` works with local storage cache and provides off-line information, but how?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JavaScript SDK, it will not work on mobile apps.

To achieve this feature, you have to add `react-native-firebase`, which is an abstraction of JavaScript SDK to both iOS and Android SDK.

https://rnfirebase.io/

After adding it to your project, you can setup the following config:

> **Android**
>
> Add `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` inside
>   your `MainApplication.java` files `onCreate()` method.
>
> You also need to explicitly add the `FirebaseDatabase` import with the
>   rest of the imports near the top of your `MainApplication.java` file:
>
> `import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;`
>
> **iOS**
>
> Add `[FIRDatabase database].persistenceEnabled = YES;` after the `[FIRApp configure];` line inside your `AppDelegate.m` files
>   `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Source: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v3.2.x/core/default-app#Enable-Database-Persistence

Also, if you want to trigger any event when the user lost connection, you can use onDisconnect listener: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/database/reference/OnDisconnect

Hope it helps